# SANE: sane-find-scanner works (now) scanimage and frontend do not

Tags: scanner, sane

Having done what I hope is due diligence in researching this answer I'm stuck. I've recompiled and installed sane and `libusb` as needed to ensure their integrity. I've also edited the various `.conf` files and ascertained the drivers are present for the hardware I have.  Upon first trial Simple Scan DID work until I loaded `xsane`.

Now, `scanimage -L` *will* see the scanner, but only when run as root (using `sudo`), not as normal user. `lsusb` sees the scanner OK as does `sane-find-sccanner`, since changing file permissions, as user.

I've tried to `chgrp` to `scanner` or `chmod to a+r-x` for all the files I could find for the various `libusb`, devices, `sane`, etc I could find.  I guess this comes down to the subtle differences in file names and locations of things in 14.04 and the answers given to others. For example, I do not have a `dev/003/010` file for any of my USB ports.

I *do* have a `usb1`, `usb2` etc which points to a more arcane set of file names...

`SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128` with `scanimage -L` didn't reveal what's missing.  I'm stuck.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04LTS
- HP-AMD64 platform
- Canon LiDE20 scanner (using Plustek .conf file and drivers)

Comment: I have an admittedly simpler case (HP wifi scanner that works out of the box) but sometime `xsane` frontend hangs. The only solution I found is deleting the directory `~/.sane` --- thing will work again for a while, and then stops again. Rinse, repeat. Could be your case, probably not. Worth a fast check.

Comment: Sometimes it may help to plug the scanner into another USB port. Prefer USB 2.0 over USB 3.0 as that may cause issues with some scanners.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a udev rule to give access to the device to the members of the `scanner` group. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184367/scanimage-does-not-find-scanner-unless-sudoed-but-shows-up-with-sane-find-scan/184463#184463 for an example.

I had to put the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", MODE="0660", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

before restarting udev (`systemctl restart udev.service`).

Then make sure that the users who need to use the scanner are in the `scanner` group:

```
adduser username scanner
```